# Making only some Lua scripts on the path runnable from the command line in Windows XP

Tags: windows, scripting, lua, console, path-variables

Note: this trick also applies to scripting languages other than Lua, or to any other document type that might be considered an application in some contexts and a document in others.

If an interpreter is already associated to handle `.lua` files in Windows (i.e. if double clicking on a `.lua` file runs it in the interpreter) it is easy to make them executable directly on the command line.

You need to:

1. put the script in a directory that is listed in the `PATH` environment variable;
2. add the `.lua` extension to the `PATHEXT` environment variable.

In this way you can run **any** Lua script by typing its name on the command line. The problem now is that you cannot put another Lua script in any directory on the PATH without risking it to be executed, even if you don't want it to be executed. (An example of such a .lua file would be a module private to your program that will be loaded by `require`. Modules are by convention also named `.lua`, but rarely support execution as a free-standing program.)

So it is an all-or-nothing situation. Either you allow any script in a directory on the path to be executed or none.

Is there a way to allow only **some** scripts **in a directory on the path** to be runnable typing their name?

Comment: If you have answered your question, then post the answer as an *answer*, not as part of your question.

Comment: As I have said *in the post* I could not answer *as an answer*, I have too low a rep! I have to wait 8 hours. It was the SO interface itself that, when trying to answer, told me I couldn't do that and to edit the question instead! Why did you erase the answer while I only followed what SO interface told me to do?

Comment: Oh, well. I'll try again. It seems my rep has already gone up. I'm still a newbie here. Sorry if I broke some rules.

Comment: I'm resisting the temptation to remove the Lua tag because Lua is really only the context for discussion of a quirk of Windows CMD.EXE name resolution using PATHEXT. The same trick applies to any other interpreted language or really any other file type.

Comment: @RBerteig I see. Effectively since I'm a newbie on SO I wasn't sure whether I should have put that only under the `scripting` umbrella. Since my use case was essentially that of Lua and the examples provided were about Lua I decided to use Lua tag for fear that without it the community could flag the post as off-topic or not well documented (my initial note reflects this mixed feeling).

Comment: As a long-term user (but no more authoritative than any other) my sense is that the Lua tag is not problematic here. Someone may come along later and retag it to something more specific to Windows command interpreters since that *is* the essential concept. But that too is consistent with SO. You ask the question in a way that is clear to you, others come along and help with context, retag to get it a better audience, or even migrate it to one of the other sites where it could be a better fit. All with the goal of making SO be the best place to find an answer when searching later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is that the console PATHEXT mechanism understands "double extensions", i.e. adding a `.exe.lua` "extension" to `PATHEXT` will make executable only those Lua scripts which have their full-name ending in `.exe.lua` (of course you can choose another extension, say `.run.lua`). Note: I used the quotes to avoid possible confusion and for lack of better terminology (remember that, conventionally, the file extension is the part of the file name **after the last** dot).

Therefore by adding `.exe.lua` to `PATHEXT` only `whatevername.exe.lua` will be executable, whereas any other Lua script won't (provided it doesn't have the same "double extension").

This allows to distinguish "normal" scripts from "executable" ones without either separating them in different directories or define a new custom file extension, which involves modification to the registry.

Moreover since this behaviour is controlled by an environment variable, it is a per-process setting - you can enable it only for a specific console window. For example if you create a batch file with this content:

```
@set PATHEXT=%PATHEXT%;.exe.lua &cmd /K
```

and you run it, it will open a console that will be able to execute all `.exe.lua` scripts found on the path, but not any other `.lua` script.

Comment: To avoid confusion, I would prefer a long extension without a dot in it, perhaps `.luaexe` or `.luax`. But your solution is IMHO the right strategy, and it was a (small) mistake by the Lua designers to use the same file name convention for Lua code that is intended to be run (a script or whole program) and code that is intended to be a module.

Comment: Another note: modify the default value of PATHEXT in the registry, for either all users (if you have admin rights) or for just your account. The easiest way to do that is to get the Advanced System Settings open (Windows+Break, Advanced System Settings) then click the button "Environment Variables". If you've installed any developer tools at all, the system value of PATHEXT is likely a lot longer than its old default of ".COM;.EXE;.BAT".

Comment: @RBerteig I discovered this trick trying to cope with a mess of extensions: I've configured my system to run `.lua` and `.luac` files with PUC Lua and `.wxlua` files with wxLua customized interpreter. An advantage of "double extension trick" is that you don't have a combinatorial explosion of "basic" extensions: I can have "regular" `.wxlua` files but also command-line-reachable `.exe.wxlua` files, but they are still both `.wxlua` files, so no need to reconfigure your editor(s), Windows file associations, etc. etc.

Comment: you are effectively leveraging the exact source of confusion that concerns me: the lack of clear definition of the term "extension". I suspect that way lies madness, but it seems like you've found a tame behavior to exploit a short way down that path. Don't forget to check what the 8.3 name ends up set to which also enters the very murky calculation of how to interpret the file; for that your pattern is better than my suggestion because the default 8.3 name for `foo.exelua` is `foo~1.exe` and it actually matches the glob `*.exe`. I personally use `.lexe` for installed Lua scripts.

Comment: @RBerteig Yes it is murky. I could not produce official docs, but I think that 8.3 filenames don't play a role here (I suspect that it's because I use NTFS, on FAT32 it may be different). If I define `foo.exe.lua` and `foo.exe.luaz` they have almost the same 8.3 name+extension (.EXE), but only the first gets executed, and even if I delete that, the second is not considered by the PATHEXT mechanism. So it seems that in practice the trick is safe from this POV (as I said, I suspect NTFS is to praise for this, but it's a gut feeling).

Comment: use DIR/X to see the 8.3 name. NTFS has a place to store it for compatibility. It can be configured off by policy, so it might not be in use, but out of the box Windows is configured to generate an 8.3 name for every long file name. The rules of construction have varied since the feature was first introduced in Win95 and FAT16 with long file name support, of course. `Foo.exe.lua` and `foo.exe.luaz` both end up with 8.3 names ending in `.LUA`: `FOOEXE~1.LUA` and `FOOEXE~2.LUA` on my Win7 Pro on an NTFS drive. And `DIR *.lua` finds both. As I said, murky.